# fragmentTransaction Variable not being used

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio

I need some help! I can't seems to declare my variable fragmentTransaction.

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager =getSupportFragmentManager();
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
```

Currently using Android Studio. Thanks!

Comment: look at the official [documantation] (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Comment: This info might help set up the v4 support library http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html